# Passing object to viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm

Question on the MVVM pattern where I think I have it wrong.

When a touchdown event occurs in a view I want to popup a message i.e.:

```
private void marker_TouchDown(MessageObject msgData)
{
    CustomMessageControl message = new CustomMessageControl() {Width = 610, Height = 332};
    CustomMessageViewModel messageVM = new CustomMessageViewModel(msgData);
    message.DataContext = messageVM;
    //Add to canvas
}
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class CustomMessageViewModel
{
    public MessageObject message { get; set; }

    public CustomMessageViewModel(MessageObject message)
    {
        this.MessageObject = message;
    }
}
```

This works but doesn't feel right. Is this an acceptable way to populate the view model?

Comment: Generally viewmodels will use the INPC interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to support notifying the view/consumer that properties have been updated. I would highly advise against redifining the datacontext in code to a new viewmodel when attached in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Quinton, I understand the use of INPC. I maybe looking at this too literally but here somebody is clicking on a view and I want to launch a new view passing some data related to the point they clicked.

Comment: Excuse my skimming over the code, you are indeed doing what is generally considered correct, it might not look so pretty in the code but is the standard way of instantiating and passing data to a viewmodel, there are several MVVM frameworks that help alleviate this in their design that might be of interest to you but if you want to handle it all manually that is generally the accepted approach.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson It's not correct, the view model is creating the user interface element; the separation of concerns that MVVM supports is violated with this.

Comment: @casperOne You are correct, I am sorry I have not been clear on this, the generation of the control was not what I was referring to but rather instantiating the viewmodel with the relevant data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are violating MVVM in creating the control in the view model.  This isn't testable, your view model *has* to create the control now and that shouldn't be a requirement for testing (this emphasizes the lack of the separation of concerns between the UI and the view model).

Instead of creating the control, it is completely acceptable for your view model to fire an event of it's own.  In this event, you'd pass the view model that you want the dialog/overlay/control to bind to, something like this:

```
public class CustomMessageControlEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CustomMessageViewModel CustomMessageViewModel { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<CustomMessageControlEventArgs> 
    ShowCustomMessageControl;

private void marker_TouchDown(MessageObject msgData)
{
    // Create the view model.
    var message = ...;

    // Get the events.
    var events = ShowCustomMessageControl;

    // Fire.
    if (events != null) events(this, 
        new CustomMessageControlEventArgs {
            MessageObject = new CustomMessageViewModel(msgData)
        });
}
```

Then, in your UI code, you would bind to the event and then show the appropriate user interface for that event.

Remember, MVVM isn't strictly about being able to declare everything in XAML or binding data to the UI through *just* data bindings, it's about proper separation of code.

You want to separate the *what* of what is displayed (the view model) from the *how* of what is displayed (the UI); in firing an event, you're maintaining that separation of concerns.

Yes, you'll have to write some code behind (or you could do it through property notification changes, but it's uglier, frankly), but it maintains the separation and allows for easy testability without having to bring in any user interface elements.